# Jewish-themed Open Source projects

Tags: technology, tzibur-community

I am a programmer and would like to begin contributing to an Open Source code base. What projects related to Judaism are under active development?

Comment: Is this "Too Localized"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't think so.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'd argue too broad!  It's a list question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses probably. Things under development now won't be in a few years; there's no permanent answer to this.

Comment: This could be recast as "how do I find...", which probably has a longer shelf-life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be that much online, but you probably could find collaborators on this site for potential projects. Below are some Torah projects on Github, they might be open to contributions:

- [Zmanim](https://github.com/Yitzchok/Zmanim)
- [opensiddur](https://github.com/opensiddur/opensiddur)
- [PocketTorah](https://github.com/rneiss/PocketTorah)
- [TorahOhr](https://github.com/SLaks/TorahOhr)
- [Open-Talmud](https://github.com/jon513/Open-Talmud)

The [Sefaria](http://sefaria.org/) project looks especially interesting:

- [Torah Texts Interface](https://github.com/blockspeiser/Sefaria-Project)
- [Torah Texts Data](https://github.com/blockspeiser/Sefaria-Data)